# Create a lot of objects and delete them

Tags: python, windows, pygame

so i'm kinda new to programming, but for now with python and pygame i'm trying to create a small game. It is quite simple, the player will move around dodging small projectiles. However i'm having trouble creating a lot of objects, for example i need to randomly generate a position and a speed for a new projectile, and how do i create many objects like that, plus when they actually go 'out of the screen' they should disapear. 
So I also need to delete them. My first idea was to create a list of objects, I and a loop that would move them one by one before updating the screen, but how do i create new objects with different names while I don't know how many projectiles will be on the screen, it should be random.

```
class Projectiles:
    ProjectilesCount = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y, speed):
            self.pos = (x,y)
            self.speed = speed
            Projectiles.ProjectilesCount += 1

    def moveProj(self):
            x, y = self.pos
            x -= self.speed
            self.pos = (x,y)
            pygame.draw.line(DISPLAY, WHITE, self.pos, (x,y+self.SIZE), self.SIZE)

bullet = Projectiles(500,200,5)
bullet.SIZE = SIZE

while true:
    # some stuff

    bullet.moveProj()

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

This is the class i use for now (it just goes left) and it works for just one projectile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dictionaries. A list will work, but when using objects where the order is not important use dictionaries. Dictionaries also perform better when iterating through lots of data within them. Use some code similar to below...

```
bulletdict = {}
#This is a list because we can change the value within a function without returning it
#You could also use a global variable instead of a list
bulletcount = [0]

def SpawnBullet(bulletdict,bulletcount):
    bulletdict[bulletcount] = Projectiles
    bulletcount[0] += 1
```

The key will be a number and the value will be the bullet itself. To iterate through the dictionary to update stuff do...

```
for item in bulletdict:
    bulletdict[item].moveproj(...)
```

If you need to remove stuff use code similar to this. I usually have 'checkDelete' functions inside my objects that I can call to check to see if we should remove them. This is used for things like deleting objects if they get off the screen or collide with something.

```
def deleteObjects(objectdict):
    deletelist = []

    for item in objectdict:
        if objectdict[item].checkdelete() == True:
            deletelist.append(item)

    for item in deletelist:
        del objectdict[item]
```

This allows for easy use and iteration of your objects. You can always tell the last spawned object because it will have the highest number as the key. This key number will also tell you the total number of spawned objects if you so need it.
I hope this helps you and good luck making your game.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i will try this when i can!

Comment: Actually this was a class project. And i will probably add more question because i don't know how to make trajectories in diagonal, and use the "sprite" method for pygame. But this already helped me a lot, so thanks!

Comment: Thanks and good luck on your project. If you need anything else with this just comment and I'll try to add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want a list:

```
list_of_bullets = []

for i in range(100):
    list_of_bullets.append(Projectiles(...))
```